# Trouble using Xpath "starts with" to parse xhtml

Tags: xpath, yql

I'm trying to parse a webpage to get posts from a forum.
The start of each message starts with the following format

```
<div id="post_message_somenumber">
```

and I only want to get the first one

I tried `xpath='//div[starts-with(@id, '"post_message_')]'` in yql without success
I'm still learning this, anyone have suggestions

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two possible causes of the problem and for solution.

Comment: The problem is with quotes and (perhaps secondarily) the value of the `id` (it doesn't start with a double quote). You want something like `xpath='//div[starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]'`

Comment: I don't know what yql is, but I suspect the issue is with how you write an XPath expression containing quotes and then embed it or escape it in your host language environment.

Comment: thanks for the responses.  Salathe, your suggestion worked.  YQL is yahoo query language and, along with yahoo pipes, is a good way for people who don't know programming to learn how to parse web pages, combine rss feeds, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I think I have a solution that does not require dealing with namespaces.

Here is one that selects **all matching div's**:

```
//div[@id[starts-with(.,"post_message")]]
```

But you said you wanted just the "first one" (I assume you mean the first "hit" in the whole page?). Here is a slight modification that selects **just the first matching result**:

```
(//div[@id[starts-with(.,"post_message")]])[1]
```

These use the dot to represent the id's value within the `starts-with()` function.  You may have to escape special characters in your language.

It works great for me in PowerShell:

```
# Load a sample xml document
$xml = [xml]'<root><div id="post_message_somenumber"/><div id="not_post_message"/><div id="post_message_somenumber2"/></root>'

# Run the xpath selection of all matching div's
$xml.selectnodes('//div[@id[starts-with(.,"post_message")]]')
```

Result:

```
id
--
post_message_somenumber
post_message_somenumber2
```

Or, for just the first match:

```
# Run the xpath selection of the first matching div
$xml.selectnodes('(//div[@id[starts-with(.,"post_message")]])[1]')
```

Result:

```
id
--
post_message_somenumber
```

Answer (score 5):

> I tried `xpath='//div[starts-with(@id,
>   '"post_message_')]'` in yql without
>   success I'm still learning this,
>   anyone have suggestions

If the problem isn't due to the many nested apostrophes and the unclosed double-quote, then the most likely cause (we can only guess without being shown the XML document) is that a default namespace is used.

Specifying names of elements that are in a default namespace is the most FAQ in XPath. If you search for "XPath default namespace" in SO or on the internet, you'll find many sources with the correct solution.

Generally, a special method must be called that binds a prefix (say `"x:"`) to the default namespace. Then, in the XPath expression every element name `"someName"` must be replaced by `"x:someName`.

Here is a **[good answer how to do this in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c)**.

Read the documentation of your language/xpath-engine how something similar should be done in your specific environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[starts-with(@id,'expiredUserDetails') and contains(text(), 'Details')]") 
private WebElementFacade ListOfExpiredUsersDetails;
```

This one gives a list of all elements on the page that share an ID of `expiredUserDetails` and also contains the text or the element `Details`