# Check Xml tag exist in xpath.

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xpath

I am trying to get value from Xml file using xpath. Here is my code:

```
XElement docQuote = XElement.Parse(Financial);
string result= docQuote.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Quote",nsmgr).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

This is working fine when `Quote` Xml node exist in XML file and return value in between `Quote` tags. However Quote xml tag not exist in the XMl file it generates and exception.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have tried to check NULL as below:

`if(docQuote.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Quote",nsmgr) != null`)

and

```
if(docQuote.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Quote",nsmgr) != null).value != null)
```

However it doesn't avoid the execution when null.

Please help me to avoid execution when Xml tag not exist.

Comment: Are you making sure your `nsmgr` object isn't null?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [boolean()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) XPATH function helps here:

```
boolean(//*[name()='Quote'])
```

If element Quote exists, `boolean(//*[name()='Quote'])` should return true, otherwise false.

```
XElement docQuote = XElement.Parse(Financial);
string result= docQuote.XPathSelectElement("boolean(//*[name()='Quote'])",nsmgr).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 XElement docQuote = XElement.Parse(Financial);
   if(docQuote != null && docQuote.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Quote",nsmgr) != null)
   {
    string result=   docQuote.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Quote",nsmgr).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
   }
```

Comment: This will not work since docQuote is not null. and when going to execute second half your check it fire the exception.

Comment: Can you show the full code.
nsmgr Financial object e.t.c

May be there is error in declaration 
Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819305/xpathselectelement-always-returns-null

P.S.
[Voted -1 :)]