# How to dynamically query XDocument using XPath when XML has namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I've been using [this absolute XPath extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451950/get-the-xpath-to-an-xelement) to get `XPath` strings of nodes inside `XDocument`'s. The node can then later be queried by XPath using `xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath)`.

However, this fails for XML documents that use namespaces, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.svsxml.svs.com" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>Pizza</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>Pie</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Calling `GetAbsoluteXPath` on the `Username` node gives:

```
/Envelope/Header[1]/Security[1]/UsernameToken[1]/Username[1]
```

However, querying the XDocument with XPathSelectElement and the above XPath yields `null`, because no namespace is specified.

According to answers I looked up, the solution is to [add a `NamespaceManager` and manually edit the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819560/4603093). However, my paths are dynamically-generated (I don't know the namespace or structure of the XML document in advance), so hand-tweaking the strings is not an option.

My question is:

- Is there a way to query using an XPath in a way which totally ignores namespaces?

[An answer to a similarly-named question was to query by local name instead of XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath). However, this fails when multiple nodes have the name LocalName (which often occurs in the XML I'm parsing), since searching by name only throws away the specificity of the XPath entirely.

**For clarification**: I don't know what the XML document looks like in advance, and the XPath and namespaces are determined at run-time, not compile-time. So manually adding strings that only work for this particular example won't work in general.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is xml linq and will work with one node.  With multiple nodes you have to add addional search info to get the exact node(s) you are looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement envelope = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace wsse =  envelope.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("wsse");
            string username = envelope.Descendants(wsse + "Username").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work because I don't know the namespace (or even what the XML looks like) in advance.

Comment: To search xml you need to know what you are looking for.  You response doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm dynamically querying an unknown XML document, so the XPath and namespaces will only be known at runtime, but not compile-time.

Comment: You can replace any hard coded string (in double quotes) with a variable so a runtime it can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and found a solution like this:

```
XDocument doc = ...
var nsmngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.CreateReader().NameTable);

foreach (var attribute in doc.Descendants().Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration))
{
    nsmngr.AddNamespace(attribute.Name.LocalName, attribute.Value);
}

// then use the namespacemanager when querying the document
var someXPath = "/Envelope/Header[1]/Security[1]/UsernameToken[1]/Username[1]";
doc.XPathEvaluate(someXPath, nsmngr)
```