# XDocument.XPathSelectElements doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, linq, xpath

Sometimes C# driving me crazy, guys :) !

I tried a very simple code:

```
String pathToXMLFile = openFileDialog2.FileName;
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXMLFile);
var xElements = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//NotificationData");
foreach (XElement xe in xElements)
{
   Console.WriteLine(xe);
   xe.RemoveAll();
}
xdoc.Save("c:/Temp/ReestrZalogovRuManyCollateralItemsSimple_output.xml");
```

and a very simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<PledgeNotificationToNotary xmlns="http://fciit.ru/eis2/ruzdi/types/2.2" version="2.2">

    <NotificationId>7d8b62c2-7682-43f8-8a2c-ef4296296210</NotificationId>

    <NotificationNotaryAddress/>

    <NotificationData version="2.2">

        <FormUZ1>

            <PersonalProperties>

                <PersonalProperty>

                    <OtherProperty>

                        <Description>Движимое имущество, согласно перечню по договору купли-продажи </Description>

                    </OtherProperty>

                </PersonalProperty>

            </PersonalProperties>

            <Pledgors>

                <Pledgor>

                    <Organization>

                        <RussianOrganization>

                            <NameFull>dgdgdfgdf</NameFull>

                            <OGRN>35345345</OGRN>

                            <INN>34534545</INN>

                            <Address>

<RegionCode>77</RegionCode>

<Region>Москва</Region>

<Street>Малая Семеновская</Street>

<House>fggdgdf</House>

<Building>dfgdfg</Building>

<Apartment>54654646dfg</Apartment>

                            </Address>

                        </RussianOrganization>

                    </Organization>

                </Pledgor>

            </Pledgors>

            <Pledgee>

                <Pledgee>

                    <Organization>

                        <RussianOrganization>

                            <NameFull>Тимер Банк (публичное акционерное общество)</NameFull>

                            <OGRN>1021600000146</OGRN>

                            <INN>1653016689</INN>

                            <Address>

<RegionCode>16</RegionCode>

<Region>Республика Татарстан (Татарстан)</Region>

<City>Казань</City>

<Street>проспект Ибрагимова</Street>

<House>58</House>

                            </Address>

                            <Email>dfgdgdgdg@timerbank.ru</Email>

                        </RussianOrganization>

                    </Organization>

                </Pledgee>

            </Pledgee>

            <PledgeContract>

                <Name>ДОГОВОР О ЗАЛОГЕ</Name>

                <Date>2018-08-20</Date>

                <Number>№ДОКЛЮ/7777/77-7</Number>

                <TermOfContract>«01» июня 2028 года</TermOfContract>

            </PledgeContract>

            <NotificationApplicant>

                <Role>2</Role>

                <Organization>

                    <NameFull>Тимер Банк (публичное акционерное общество)</NameFull>

                    <URN>1021600000146</URN>

                    <UINN>1653016689</UINN>

                    <Email>fgdfggsdfgsdfg@timerbank.ru</Email>

                </Organization>

                <Attorney>

                    <Name>

                        <Last>dfgfg</Last>

                        <First>dfgsdfg</First>

                        <Middle>sdfgdfg</Middle>

                    </Name>

                    <BirthDate>1967-08-01</BirthDate>

                    <Authority>приказ dgdfgdfgfdg</Authority>

                    <PersonDocument>

                        <Code>33</Code>

                        <Name>Паспорт гражданина Российской Федерации</Name>

                        <SeriesNumber>2323 232323</SeriesNumber>

                    </PersonDocument>

                    <PersonAddress>

                        <AddressRF registration="true">

                            <RegionCode>16</RegionCode>

                            <Region>Республика Татарстан (Татарстан)</Region>

                            <City>Казань</City>

                            <Street>gfdgdfg</Street>

                            <House>343434</House>

                        </AddressRF>

                    </PersonAddress>

                </Attorney>

            </NotificationApplicant>

        </FormUZ1>

    </NotificationData>

</PledgeNotificationToNotary>
```

The problem is `xdoc.XPathSelectElements` in this code doesn't return any Elements.

I thought, may be I haven't yet woken up and tried to test my XML and XPath in the first site in Google for XPath online evulation - https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and my XPath `//NotificationData` works with this XML like a charm.

But why it doesn't work in C#? :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to specify the namespace in the query. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819305/xpathselectelement-always-returns-null

Comment: I tought about it. But what namespace will be for my case? Thank you!

Comment: Add an XmlNamespaceManager to the query, see the accepted answer.

Comment: OK, but how to disable NS processing, how to ignore them? In this case it's a simpliest code and I don't need to process them.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't ignore them.

Comment: How can I figure out, what NS prefix should be for my XML, for NS "http://fciit.ru/eis2/ruzdi/types/2.2"? The main problem, that I haven't any docs and I am programming this code "blindly".

Comment: You can pick your own name, see the accepted answer in the before mentioned question.

Comment: Interesting... But there are no prefixes in original XML file, all tags are used without any prefixes and look like `<PersonalProperties>`, not like `<someNSPrefix:PersonalProperties>`... I understood that answer, but still can't understand, why it will be applied only for elements without NS.