# Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C# for Canonicalisation

Tags: c#, xpath, namespaces, canonicalization

I'm trying to apply the C14N transform to some generated XML. It appears I can't use LINQ to retrieve the nodes to perform the canonicalisation so I have to go 'old school' with the DOM but I think I'm falling foul of the default namespace.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

    // Load some test xml
    string path = @"..\..\TestFiles\Test_1.xml";
    if (File.Exists(path) == true)
    { 
        xDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            xDoc.Load(fs);
        }
    }

    //Instantiate an XmlNamespaceManager object. 
    System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

    //Add the namespaces used in books.xml to the XmlNamespaceManager.
    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("", "http://www.myApps.co.uk/");

    // Create a list of nodes to have the Canonical treatment
        //Execute the XPath query using the SelectNodes method of the XmlDocument.
        //Supply the XmlNamespaceManager as the nsmgr parameter.
        //The matching nodes will be returned as an XmlNodeList.
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/ApplicationsBatch/Applications|/ApplicationsBatch/Applications//*", xmlnsManager);

    // Perform the C14N transform on the data
    XmlDsigC14NTransform transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();

    transform.LoadInput(nodeList);
    MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)transform.GetOutput(typeof(Stream));

    File.WriteAllBytes(@"..\..\TestFiles\ModifiedTest_1", ms.ToArray());
}
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ApplicationsBatch xmlns="http://www.myApps.co.uk/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MessageHeader>
    <MessageID>00000003</MessageID>
    <Body>11223344556</Body>
    <Timestamp>2011-08-02T09:00:00</Timestamp>
    <MessageCheck>?</MessageCheck>
  </MessageHeader>
  <Applications>
    <Application>
      <ApplicantDetails>
        <Title>MR</Title>
        <Forename>HOMER</Forename>
        <Middlenames>
          <Middlename></Middlename>
        </Middlenames>
        <PresentSurname>SIMPSON</PresentSurname>
        <CurrentAddress>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>ADDRESS LINE1</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>ADDRESS LINE2</AddressLine2>
            <AddressTown>ADDRESS Town</AddressTown>
            <AddressCounty>COUNTY</AddressCounty>
            <Postcode>POST CODE</Postcode>
            <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
          </Address>
          <ResidentFromGyearMonth>2007-01</ResidentFromGyearMonth>
        </CurrentAddress>
      </ApplicantDetails>
    </Application>
    <Application>
      <ApplicantDetails>
        <Title>MR</Title>
        <Forename>BART</Forename>
        <Middlenames>
          <Middlename></Middlename>
        </Middlenames>
        <PresentSurname>SIMPSON</PresentSurname>
        <CurrentAddress>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>ADDRESS LINE1</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>ADDRESS LINE2</AddressLine2>
            <AddressTown>ADDRESS Town</AddressTown>
            <AddressCounty>COUNTY</AddressCounty>
            <Postcode>POST CODE</Postcode>
            <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
          </Address>
          <ResidentFromGyearMonth>2007-01</ResidentFromGyearMonth>
        </CurrentAddress>
      </ApplicantDetails>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</ApplicationsBatch>
```

I've read a few other topics around the area and came across this [Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c) but it's not solved the problem.

Using the XPath Visualiser shows the required nodes should be selected but my code fails to select any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a partial answer to my problem.

When a new namespace is added to the manager it appears that the default namespace can't be an empty string.
This is what I ended up with:

```
//Instantiate an XmlNamespaceManager object. 
System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

//Add the namespaces used to the XmlNamespaceManager.
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.myApps.co.uk/");
```

I then needed to modify the XPath to reflect the namespace identifier like this:

```
// Create a list of nodes to have the Canonical treatment
    //Execute the XPath query using the SelectNodes method of the XmlDocument.
    //Supply the XmlNamespaceManager as the nsmgr parameter.
    //The matching nodes will be returned as an XmlNodeList.
XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/x:ApplicationsBatch/x:Applications|/x:ApplicationsBatch/x:Applications//*", xmlnsManager);
```

The nodes are now selected and ready for transformation... although that returns the correct structure of XML but all the values have been removed but that is a problem for another question.

Comment: You meant to say you cannot specify a default namespace for use with xpath.  It makes sense, since xpath will range over multiple nodes with multiple prefixes, and more importantly will have to deal with nodes with a null namespace, which would look like a default namespace in xpath.  Within the XML you have the context to help determine if it is a default or a null namespace.