# Reading an attribute through XPath in xml document does not work

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have a simple xml document below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Research researchID="RT_a" language="eng" xmlns="http://www.rixml.org/2010/1/RIXML" createDateTime="2012-06-30T01:13:38Z">
  <Product productID="RT_a">
              <SecurityID idType="ISIN" idValue="US0605051046" />
  </Product>
</Research>
```

I am trying to read an attribute "idValue" with the give XPath string. This does not work unless I remove this part:

```
xmlns="http://www.rixml.org/2010/1/RIXML"
```

My code is below:

```
    Dim doc As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument("c:\test\test.xml")

    Dim strXPath As String = "/Research[1]/Product[1]/SecurityID[1]"
    Dim nav As XPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator()
    Dim mgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable)

    mgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.rixml.org/2010/1/RIXML")

    Dim XPathNode As XPathNavigator = nav.SelectSingleNode(strXPath, mgr)
    If XPathNode IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(XPathNode.GetAttribute("idValue", String.Empty))
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Nothing found")
    End If
```

The row about adding name space have no effect on result - just did some tests with that. What do I need to do/what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim strXPath As String = "/x:Research[1]/x:Product[1]/x:SecurityID[1]/@idValue"
Dim nav As XPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator()
Dim mgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable)

mgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.rixml.org/2010/1/RIXML")
nav.Evaluate("string(" + strXPath + ")", mgr)
```

It should return your ID value, or then an empty string if the attribute is not found.

I think the problem may have been the one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911160/1025176), that you must explicitly refer to the namespace (even if it is the default one), so by using "x:" you fix it.