# Reading attribute of an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML file, I can read all the the nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04">
    <CTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte">
        <infCte versao="1.04" ID="CTe3512110414557000014604"></infCte>
    </CTe>
</cteProc>
```

I have tried reading this using C#

```
string chavecte;        
string CaminhoDoArquivo = @"C:\Separados\13512004-procCTe.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(CaminhoDoArquivo); //Carregando o arquivo
chavecte = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("infCTe")
                    .Attributes.GetNamedItem("Id").ToString();
```

but something is wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of XML namespaces?

Comment: Your XML sample missing Id attribute...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c-sharp) - most likely reason is lack of using namespaces in selecting "infCte" node as covered in this question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Linq To Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(CaminhoDoArquivo);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte";
var chavecte = xDoc.Descendants(ns+"infCte").First().Attribute("id").Value;
```

PS: I am assuming your xml's invalid line is as

```
<infCte versao="1.04" id="CTe3512110414557000014604"></infCte>
```

Comment: Thanks the code work perfect. I have write wrong , i forget "id"

Comment: +1. For correct answer and especially for magically knowing that @alejandrocarnero does not care about what XML parsing classes to use.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
chavecte = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("infCTe").Attributes.GetNamedItem("Id").Value;
```

with

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte");

chavecte = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ab:infCte", nsmgr)
                 .Attributes.GetNamedItem("Id").Value;
```

I've also noticed that `infCte` doesn't have the ID attribute properly defined in your xml

Comment: It is unlikely to help since XPath to the "infCte" node does not include "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" namespace.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry, when some people tell you "it doesn't work" it's sometimes hard to find all the reasons.  I'll look at that and then edit as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is:

```
string CaminhoDoArquivo = @"C:\Separados\13512004-procCTe.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(CaminhoDoArquivo); //Carregando o arquivo

// Select the node you're interested in
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/cteProc/CTe/infCte");
// Read the value of the attribute "ID" of that node
string chavecte = node.Attributes["ID"].Value;
```