# Reading XML Node in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET within VS2008.

Sample XML FIle

```
<MailListExportXML xsi:schemaLocation="com.efi.planner.mailing.export MonarchMailListExport.xsd" xmlns="com.efi.planner.mailing.export" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MailListFiles>
  <MailListFile MailListID="1" MailListName="Test Mail File 11-14-2013.csv" MailListDateTimeStamp="2013-12-04T19:18:00Z" MailListFileLocationPath="c:ImportedMailFiles" StatedFirstRecord="George Vaisey" StatedLastRecord="Mary Smith" TotalMailListRecordCount="1992"/></MailListFiles>
</MailListExportXML>
```

I am struggling to get value from MailListName to populate to a text box.

Comment: I've got code I've been working on but didn't think I should post it as its failing with syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default namespace, so you'll need to specify the namespace in `XPath` query using `XmlNamespaceManager` :

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml")
Dim namespaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("d", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("d:MailListExportXML/d:MailListFiles/d:MailListFile[@MailListID=1]")
MyTextBox.Text = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("MailListName").Value
```

Reference : [[SO Post about XPath query to select nodes having default namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/585822/2998271)]

**UPDATE :**

My bad, I missed one thing, in previous snippet namespaceManager was not used. So as confirmed by OP, this line in previous snippet :

```
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("d:MailListExportXML/d:MailListFiles/d:MailListFile[@MailListID=1]")
```

should be like this instead (note `namespaceManager` as second parameter of `SelectSingleNode` function) :

```
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("d:MailListExportXML/d:MailListFiles/d:MailListFile[@MailListID=1]", namespaceManager)
```

Comment: Name space manager worked great but produced an error about an invalid token.  I had to change the doc.selectsinglenote to reference the namespacemanager and it worked.  Revised line is below..

Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("d:MailListExportXML/d:MailListFiles/d:MailListFile[@MailListID=1]", namespaceManager)

Comment: my bad, forgot to use the `namespaceManager`. You are correct, without passing it as parameter of `SelectSingleNode` it is useless to create `namespaceManager`. Updated my answer to clarify that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load(PATH TO XML FILE)

Dim docNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("MailListExportXML/MailListFiles/MailListFile[@MailListID=1]")
SOMETEXTBOX.Text = docNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("MailListName").Value
xmlDoc = Nothing
```

based on you error, make sure the **xmlDoc.Load(**... IS THE PATH AND NAME OF THE ACTUAL XML DOCUMENT. below is a MapPath example but you can use the absolute path like "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapp\App_Data\Mailing.xml"

```
Dim xml_doc As XmlDataDocument = New XmlDataDocument()
xml_doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/NAME AND PATH OF XML FILE.xml"))
Dim docNode As XmlNode = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("MailListExportXML/MailListFiles/MailListFile[@MailList‌​ID=1]")
tbMMInputFile.Text = docNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("MailListName").Value
xmlDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: Here is the code I'm using that generates an error about an empty url.
<cr>
Dim xml_doc As XmlDataDocument = New XmlDataDocument
xml_doc.Load(tbMMInputFile.Text)

Dim docNode As XmlNode = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("MailListExportXML/MailListFiles/MailListFile[@MailListID=1]")
tbMMInputFile.Text = docNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("MailListName").Value

Answer (score 0):

Using the example with the "namespacemanager" resolved the problems.