# Why is the empty namespace not working with .NET System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document xmlns="file:///someurl/goes.here">
  <levelone>
    <leveltwo>
      <title>Test Title</title>
      <item>Item 1</item>
      <item>Item 2</item>
      <item>Item 3</item>
    </leveltwo>
  </levelone>
</document>
```

And this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument fileIn = new XmlDocument();
    fileIn.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(fileIn.NameTable);
    nsm.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "file:///someurl/goes.here");
    XmlNode docElem = fileIn.DocumentElement;
    string title = docElem.SelectSingleNode("levelone/leveltwo/title", nsm).InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + title);
    Console.WriteLine("Items: " + docElem.SelectNodes("//item", nsm).Count);
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

If I run this, I get a `NullReferenceException` when I attempt to get the `InnerText` of the node I'm attempting to select for `title`. However, if I change my `AddNamespace` call to `nsm.AddNamespace("a", "file:///someurl/goes.here")` and update all of my XPaths to use that `a` namespace, then it works fine.

My understanding is that elements without the prefixes in an XPath refer to the empty namespace. [`String.Empty` is said to be for the empty namespace in MSDN's docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace(v=vs.100).aspx#remarksToggle), and I'm giving the `NamespaceManager` the correct namespace URI for the empty namespace. Yet it doesn't seem to be working and I find myself having to make a dummy namespace in the manager to get it to work right, which is really annoying. Why do I have to use this, or any workaround?

***I am not looking for a way to get my code to run,*** I know of a couple ways and detailed one widely-accepted method above. I want to know why my understanding of the documentation is resulting in broken code - e.g. is this an issue on Microsoft's end or am I just misunderstanding something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does NamespaceManager not use DefaultNamespace when using no prefix in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630995/why-does-namespacemanager-not-use-defaultnamespace-when-using-no-prefix-in-xpath)

Comment: You are misunderstanding something. Did you read the **Note** directly underneath the text you are talking about on that MSDN page?

Comment: @JLRishe Okay, I see that it says "...a prefix must be specified." However, immediately after that, it says "If an XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is the empty namespace." What does that mean, exactly? It seems worded odd and I understand that as that the given URI will be assigned to the empty namespace...

Comment: The empty namespace, a.k.a. the null namespace, is the namespace with no URI. I.e. the namespace that this element is in: `<a xmlns=""></a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML elements are bound to the namespace `file:///someurl/goes.here`. Although a namespace-prefix isn't used (or required) for the XML content, you need to register and then use a namespace-prefix in your XPath if you want to address any of those  elements that are bound to a namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xpath-queries-and-namespaces#the-default-namespace

> XPath treats the empty prefix as the `null` namespace. In other words, only prefixes mapped to namespaces can be used in XPath queries. This means that if you want to query against a namespace in an XML document, even if it is the default namespace, you need to define a prefix for it.

An XPath that does not have a namespace-prefix is addressing items in the null "no namespace" and your XML content is bound to a namespace. So, you must use a namespace-prefix (that is defined and refers to the namespace-uri) in your XPath.

Change your code to register a prefix for that URI (doesn't matter what you use). For the purpose of this example, let's use the namespace-prefix "x":

```
nsm.AddNamespace("x", "file:///someurl/goes.here");
```

And then adjust your XPath to use that namespace-prefix:

```
string title = docElem.SelectSingleNode("x:levelone/x:leveltwo/x:title", nsm).InnerText;
Console.WriteLine("Title: " + title);
Console.WriteLine("Items: " + docElem.SelectNodes("//x:item", nsm).Count);
```