# Extracting XML tags values

Tags: c#, xml

I have a list of XML files that I need to extract 3 values from each file.
The XML looks somewhat like :

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" moodCode="EVN" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <title>Summary</title>

  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <patient>
        <name>
          <given>John</given>
          <given>S</given>
          <family>Doe</family>
        </name>
       <birthTime value="19480503" />
```

I'm trying to extract given name, family name and birth time.

Initially I'm trying to print out the values using:

```
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.Load(@"Z:\\DATA\\file.XML");

XmlElement root = doc2.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList list = root.GetElementsByTagName("name");
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list.Item(i).Value);
}
```

I'm not getting any value printed, but when I debug and check the inner values of "list" I can see what I need from that tag.

How can I extract the needed information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code and all other answers ignore the default namespace `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"`

I find [Linq2Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) easier to use, so I'll post an answer using it..

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

var @namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3";

XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", @namespace);
XNamespace ns = @namespace;

var names = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ns:patient/ns:name", namespaceManager).ToList();

var list = names.Select(p => new
                 {
                     Given = string.Join(", ", p.Elements(ns + "given").Select(x => (string)x)),
                     Family = (string)p.Element(ns + "family"),
                     BirthTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddSeconds( (int)p.Parent.Element(ns + "birthTime").Attribute("value"))
                 })
           .ToList();
```

Comment: What does that namespace do? also how can I include the birth time tag?

Comment: @WT86 First test the answer, Then read some docs about xml and if you still can't find an answer how to include *birthday* I can help you happily..

Comment: @EZI Will do :)

Comment: @WT86 I added the code for birthday... The value of it is the number of seconds since epoch(1/1/1970).... So it is `Aug 14th 1970 11:15:03`

Comment: @ErikPhilips What is the change you made in the post. I don't see any difference....

Comment: @L.B Click on the link [edited XX minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39601052/revisions).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I did already, And still don't see any difference.......  Anyway I rolled it back.... If you have a suggestion, please post it as a comment before editing....

Comment: I edited Link2Xml to point to Msdns Link to Xml Page for future users...

Comment: @ErikPhilips OK, I added it.... Next time please leave a comment about what you have changed,,,,,

Comment: I'll never do that, [it's insanely obvious in the revisions what I did](http://imgur.com/a/Gosif).

Comment: @ErikPhilips But what I see is this: http://postimg.org/image/436v7rrgz/  Like removing and adding the same thing.....

Comment: Viewing only the result and not the mark-down will definitely hide a lot of additional information.

Comment: @ErikPhilips So finally... Don't edit my answers.... Upvote/Downvote/Leave comment, but don't edit... It is my way...

Comment: This answer's edits are being discussed [on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334939/215552).

Comment: "Don't edit my answers" isn't how Stack Overflow works. You're going to have to live with the occasional edit if it improves the post

Comment: "Your way".... Not really your choice. That's not Stack's way... You can disagree, but at the end of the day that is how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.Load(@"Path\To\XmlFile.xml");

XmlElement root = doc2.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList list = root.GetElementsByTagName("name");

var names = list[0].ChildNodes;

for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i].InnerText);
}
```

Output:

```
John
S
Doe
```

There are 2 issues with your code:

- The first being that you were iterating around the `name` element, which only has a `Count` of 1 (as there is only one of these). That's why I included `list[0],ChildNodes`, to get all the children of the `name` element (`given`, `given` and `family`).
- To retrieve the text inside each element, ("John", "S", "Doe"), you should use `InnerText` instead of `Value`

Comment: you beat me to it :)  Good answer

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear from your example XML if there is only ever one `<name>` element or if there could be multiple. The following assumes there might be multiple. It also grabs the birthdate.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var xmlNode = list.Item(i).FirstChild;

    while (xmlNode != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xmlNode.InnerText);
        xmlNode = xmlNode.NextSibling;
    }
}

XmlNodeList birthDates = root.GetElementsByTagName("birthTime");

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(birthDates[i].Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If there are multiple `<patient>` elements in your xml you could do:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("a.xml");
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsm.AddNamespace("x", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
        var patients = doc.XPathSelectElements("//x:patient", nsm);
        foreach (var patient in patients)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(patient.XPathSelectElement("./x:name/x:given[1]", nsm).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(patient.XPathSelectElement("./x:name/x:given[2]", nsm).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(patient.XPathSelectElement("./x:name/x:family", nsm).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(patient.XPathSelectElement("./x:birthTime", nsm).Attribute("value").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Why do you need to add the name space explicitly even if it's a default name space in the xml? see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911160/2377787)