# How to find XML nodes when there is a xmlns=

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Visual Studio creates ".trx" files when it runs tests and I am trying to process the XML in these files. However I am getting unexpected results when trying to access parts of the XML with Xpath expressions.

The code below includes a cut down version of a ".trx" file. The files contain an `xmlns="..."` attribute that appears to prevent the Xpath accesses. The accesses work and find the expected nodes when the `xmlns...` is removed.

How do I change the name space manager (`manager`) or the Xpaths in the code (or something else) so that I can get the list of nodes matching various Xpaths in the unmodified XML.

I have tried adding `manager.AddNamespace("ns", trxContent.NamespaceURI);` and including `ns:` in the Xpaths, but without success.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace XpathXmlns
{
    class XpathXmlns
    {
        static string WithXmlns = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<TestRun id=""111"" name=""someName"" runUser=""someUser"" xmlns=""http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010""> tr1
  <TestSettings name=""Local1"" id=""222"" idx=""333""> ts2
    <Description>Description 1 context.</Description> ts3
  </TestSettings> tr4
  <TestSettings name=""Local2"" id=""333"" idx=""444""> ts5
    <Description>Description 2 context.</Description> ts6
  </TestSettings> tr7
</TestRun>
";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string WithoutXmlns = WithXmlns.Replace(@" xmlns=""http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010""", "");

            ProcessXml("WithXmnns", WithXmlns);
            ProcessXml("WithoutXmlns", WithoutXmlns);
        }

        static int counter = 0;
        static XmlNamespaceManager manager;

        static void ProcessXml(string label, string xml)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(label);
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            XmlDocument trxContent = new XmlDocument();
            trxContent.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNameTable xmlnt = trxContent.NameTable;
            manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlnt);
            //manager.AddNamespace("ns", trxContent.NamespaceURI);

            XmlNode root = trxContent.DocumentElement;

            Extract(trxContent, "//TestRun");
            Extract(trxContent, "//TestRun/TestSettings");
            Extract(trxContent, "//TestRun/TestSettings/Description");
            Extract(trxContent, "//Description");
            Extract(trxContent, "//TestSettings/@id");
            //Extract(trxContent, "//@id"); // This works OK, it finds the nodes in both cases.
            //Extract(trxContent, "//@idx"); // This works OK, it finds the nodes in both cases.
            Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestRun");
            Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestRun/TestSettings");
            Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestRun/TestSettings/Description");
            Extract(trxContent, "//ns:Description");
            Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestSettings/@id");
        }

        static void Extract(XmlDocument doc, string xpath)
        {
            counter = 0;
            ExtractNodes("doc-node", doc, xpath);
            ExtractDocNodes("doc", doc, xpath);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void ExtractNodes(string source, XmlNode root, string xpath)
        {
            counter++;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes(xpath, manager);
            ListFoundNodes(source, xpath, nodes);
        }
        private static void ExtractDocNodes(string source, XmlDocument root, string xpath)
        {
            counter++;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes(xpath, manager);
            ListFoundNodes(source, xpath, nodes);
        }

        private static void ListFoundNodes(string source, string xpath, XmlNodeList nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    {0,2}: Get {1} from {2} {3}", counter, nodes.Count, source, xpath);
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("             Nodes  name='{0}'", node.Name ?? "__None__");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using XmlDocument rather than the (easier, newer and LINQ-friendly) XDocument?

Comment: Search for "XPath default namespace" and find another 1000 answers to this question.

Comment: @spender Thank you for suggesting `XDocument`, I will look at that. I used `XmlDocument` because it was the method on the Microsoft pages I found.

Comment: @MichaelKay There are many Q&As about this topic. I have view several found by the search term you suggest. They seem dissimilar to my question. Perhaps they are the same but the way those Q&As are phrased did not match my understanding of the problem.

Comment: Here's one that pretty well identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c-sharp If you don't recognize it as identical, then that may be because you haven't mastered the terminology, in which case it would help to do more background reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xmlns attribute defines xml namespace of element. So, your `TestRun` element (and **all elements under it**) belong to the namespace `http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010`. So first you have to add that namespace to the manager:

```
XmlNameTable xmlnt = trxContent.NameTable;
manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlnt);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", @"http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010");
```

If you don't want to hardcode it, you can use namespace of the root element:

```
XmlNode root = trxContent.DocumentElement;
XmlNameTable xmlnt = trxContent.NameTable;
manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlnt);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", root.NamespaceURI);
```

Then you have to use that namespace prefix you defined (`ns`) in your queries:

```
Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestRun");
// note that all subelements (like TestSettings) are also prefixed
Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestRun/ns:TestSettings");
Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestRun/ns:TestSettings/ns:Description");
Extract(trxContent, "//ns:Description");
Extract(trxContent, "//ns:TestSettings/@id");
```

Comment: After lots of experimenting on my part I wrote the question and now you have provided a solution within just a few minutes. Thank you.