# Parsing XML in C# to retrieve values

Tags: c#, xml

I need to parse and read values from the following XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Patients xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Person xmlns="http://ehr.org/VM/" NationalCode="1234" LastName="Morgan" FirstName="Alen">
    </Person>
</Patients>
```

And I'm trying to read name of patients and birthday details using following code but for some reason xml.SelectNodes("/Patients/Person") is null, any idea how can I read the values from the xml?

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); 

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Patients/Person");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName  = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Probably the namespace on the Person element.

Comment: Take a look at [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/585812/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to fix.

First, the `Person` type in your XML is scoped to a namespace, so you need to include that namespace (via a `XmlNamespaceManager`) when you search for that node.

To do this, you add the namespace via the `AddNamespace` method and give it an alias and the namespace you want to use in your search. In my example, I used the alias `ehr`.

Then, provide the namespace manager into `.SelectNodes()` and prefix the "Person" in your search string with your alias (ex: `/Patients/ehr:Person`)

Second, the `FirstName` and `LastName` items are attributes, which you must access via the `Attributes` property.  Just using `xn["FirstName"]` will look for a child node with that name.

Here's the working code:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ehr", "http://ehr.org/VM/");

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Patients/ehr:Person", nsmgr);
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{

     string firstName = xn.Attributes["FirstName"].Value;
     string lastName = xn.Attributes["LastName"].Value;
}
```