# Select a XML node based on a sibling node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to select an XML node, where another child of the parent node contains a specific value.

The XML looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<AuthorIT>
    <Objects>
        <Media>don't care</Media>
        <Style>don't care</Style>
        <Book>don't care</Book>
        <Topic>don't care</Topic>
        <Topic>
            <Object>
                <Description>Performance Evidence</Description>
            </Object>
            <Text>This is what I want to select</Text>
        </Topic>
    </Objects>
</AuthorIT>
```

I'm using XPath in C#. My query at the moment looks like this: (but doesn't work, obviously)

```cs
docNav = new XPathDocument(localFile);
nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
xPath = "//Topic[Object/Description = 'Performance Evidence']/Text";
string value = nav.SelectSingleNode(xPath).Value;
```

How do I get the contents of the Text node, from the Topic that has an Object/Description value of "Performance Evidence"?

Comment: Your XPath is correct. Can you specify what exactly is not working?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk nav.SelectSingleNode(xPath) is returning null. If I have the XPath correct, am I doing something wrong with the rest of the c#?

Comment: So... I've been trying to get the data through other methods. I can traverse the tree using an XmlDocument and foreach(XmlNode node in xmlNodeList), but not through xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(...). I'd rather not have 5+ nested foreach loops just to find the node I want... Any suggestions, or should I make this a new question?

Comment: Made a new question. Still no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Kirill Polishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787016/kirill-polishchuk) said in a comment, my XPath was correct.

What I left out of the example XML was the key to the solution... Namespace!

I found my answer on this other question: [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You should first select the Description node containing your needle text, then move back to the common parent and select the Text nodes that are its children.

```
//Topic/Object/Description[text()='Performance Evidence']/../../Text/text()
```