# How can XML nodes be edited?

Tags: c#, xml

I got an XML field and I need to edit its node contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
         xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
</Invoice>
```

What I tried is

```
var Xdocument = new XmlDocument();
Xdocument.Load("data.xml");

var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(Xdocument.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");

var el = Xdocument.SelectNodes("/Invoice/cbc:ProfileID",nsm);
```

The variable `el` returns 0 nodes.

Comment: Invoice is the root already. Try "/cbc:ProfileID"

Comment: I tried ```var el01= Xdocument.SelectNodes("/Invoice", nsm);
            var el02 = Xdocument.SelectNodes("/cbc:ProfileID",nsm);```
But both gives me no nodes

Comment: I think you need to add the default namespace too  (`xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"`)

Comment: I Can't because the tag is reserver:
```Prefix "xmlns" is reserved for use by XML```

Comment: You are using XDocument not XmlDocument (xml linq).  Should be : XDocument Xdocument = XDocument.Load("data.xml");  You are using "new XmlDocument()" which is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the default namespace: "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" and use the XPath: "/inv:Invoice/cbc:ProfileID".

```cs
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(Xdocument.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("inv", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"); 
nsm.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");
        
var el = Xdocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/inv:Invoice/cbc:ProfileID", nsm);

Console.WriteLine(el.Item(0).InnerText);
```

To edit the value (`InnerText`) for the selected XPath, you should do as:

```cs
el.Item(0).InnerText = /* New value */;
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQFfG8)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

> How can XML nodes be edited?

With LINQ it becomes a one line operation via `.SetValue()` method.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    string inputFile = @"e:\Temp\input.xml";
    string outputFile = @"e:\Temp\ouput.xml";
    string ProfileID = "WhateverValue";

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(inputFile);

    XNamespace ns1 = xDoc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("cbc");
    xDoc.Descendants(ns1 + "ProfileID").FirstOrDefault()?.SetValue(ProfileID);
    
    xDoc.Save(outputFile);
}
```